# Finding consecutive 7 days absent employee from attendance table neglecting week off and holiday in sql server R2

Tags: sql-server

here is my attendance table details

```
Emp_id  Emp_name      PDate       status
000002  Pramod      2014-01-11      A
000002  Pramod      2014-01-12      WO
000002  Pramod      2014-01-13      A
000002  Pramod      2014-01-14      A
000002  Pramod      2014-01-15      H
000002  Pramod      2014-01-16      A
000002  Pramod      2014-01-17      A
000002  Pramod      2014-01-18      A
000002  Pramod      2014-01-19      WO
000002  Pramod      2014-01-20      A
000002  Pramod      2014-01-21      A
```

A : Absent

WO:Week off

H :Holiday

i have other employee data who is having status P(present) also but i need to fetch those who are continuously absent for 7 days without considering weekoff and holiday ......

Comment: Maybe you should use some kind of formatting for your table? That's quite difficult to understand...

Comment: Could you include your expected output?

Comment: Apart from 'what have you tried', please also include all the necessary info into your question, and avoid sending readers off site to view images - please paste the data as a textual table. We'll also need to know where information about week(end's?) off and holidays comes from, presumably other tables in your database?

Comment: You can use cursor for doing this , using cursor you can go through each line and you can set a  variable for absent count ,and when H or WO is coming do nothing and move the cursor to the next line. and if any present is before count >7 then  you can break cursor ., But using cursor is not a good idea

Comment: Add your SQL Server version and expected output (what does "consecutive 7 absence" mean?) @ArunPrasanth while a cursor would probably work here, it is a ***terrible*** idea and will perform horribly. Views (probably recursive; I'm not sure what the OP actually wants) and/or self joins are the way to go.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName thanks for remaining me the draw backs of cursor

Comment: @JamesZ - "Pramod" is a name

Comment: i have other employee data who is having status P(present) also but i need to fetch those who are continuously absent for 7 days without considering weekoff and holiday

Comment: i just need the employee name or id as output if he is absent for consecutive days..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will this do?

```
CREATE TABLE Attendance(
    Emp_id      VARCHAR(10),
    Emp_name    VARCHAR(10),
    PDate       DATE,
    Status      VARCHAR(2)
)
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES
('000002', 'Pramod', '2014-01-11', 'A'),
('000002', 'Pramod', '2014-01-12', 'WO'),
('000002', 'Pramod', '2014-01-13', 'A'),
('000002', 'Pramod', '2014-01-14', 'A'),
('000002', 'Pramod', '2014-01-15', 'H'),
('000002', 'Pramod', '2014-01-16', 'A'),
('000002', 'Pramod', '2014-01-17', 'A'),
('000002', 'Pramod', '2014-01-18', 'A'),
('000002', 'Pramod', '2014-01-19', 'A'),
('000002', 'Pramod', '2014-01-20', 'P'),
('000002', 'Pramod', '2014-01-21', 'A');

;WITH GroupedDates AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        DateGroup = DATEADD(DD, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_id ORDER BY PDate), PDate)
    FROM Attendance
    WHERE
        Status IN('A', 'WO', 'H')
)
SELECT 
    Emp_id,
    Emp_name,
    StartDate   =   MIN(PDate),
    EndDate     =   MAX(PDate),
    Days        =   DATEDIFF(DD, MIN(PDate), MAX(PDate)) + 1 
                    - SUM((CASE WHEN Status IN('WO', 'H') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
FROM GroupedDates
GROUP BY 
    Emp_id, Emp_name, DateGroup
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >=7
ORDER BY 
    Emp_id, Emp_name, StartDate

DROP TABLE Attendance
```